# Show result from an SQLite Database in PDF using Itext

Tags: java, android, sqlite, pdf, itext

I am a complete beginner in the coding World and I am trying to use IText to generate PDF from my App. I managed to create basic PDF with text, table etc..
Now I want to retrieve data from a database that is already created and not empty.
I looked on many topics over StackOverflow and on Internet without being able to make this working.

Any help will be welcome

Please let me know if you need anything else and thanks in advance !

Here are my code :

ReportActivity

```
public class ReportActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

public void onClick_report(View view) {
    try {
        createPdf();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

    File pdfFolder = new File(getExternalFilesDir("report"), "report");
    Date date = new Date();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(date);
    File myFile = new File(pdfFolder + timeStamp + ".pdf");
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    Cursor cursor = db.getSepficItem();

    //Step 1
    Document document = new Document();

    //Step 2
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);

    //Step 3
    document.open();

    //Step 4 Add content

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6);

    table.addCell("id col");
    table.addCell("day col");
    table.addCell("month col");
    table.addCell("Year col");
    table.addCell("type col");
    table.addCell("amount col");
    table.addCell("comment col");
    table.addCell("photo col");
    table.addCell("cust col");

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int count = cursor.getCount();

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
        table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("day")));
        table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("month")));
        table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("year")));
        table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")));
        table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("amount")));
        table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("comment")));
        table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("photo")));
        table.addCell(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("customername")));

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    //Step 5: Close the document
    document.close();
}
```

DataBaseHelper :

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 18;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ExpenseNote";

//Table Customer
private static final String TABLE_CUST = "Customer";
private static final String CUST_ID = "id";
private static final String CUST_NAME = "name";

//Table Expense
private static final String TABLE_EXPENSE = "Expense";
private static final String EXPENS_ID = "id";
private static final String EXPENS_DAY = "day";
private static final String EXPENS_MONTH = "month";
private static final String EXPENS_YEAR = "year";
private static final String EXPENS_TYPE = "type";
private static final String EXPENS_AMOUNT = "amount";
private static final String EXPENS_COMMENT = "comment";
private static final String EXPENS_PHOTO = "photo";
private static final String EXPENS_CUST = "customername";


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Category table create query
    String CREATE_ITEM_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TABLE_CUST + "("
            + CUST_ID + " integer primary key,"
            + CUST_NAME + " text not null)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEM_TABLE);

    String CREATE_EXPENSE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + TABLE_EXPENSE + "("
            + EXPENS_ID + " integer PRIMARY KEY,"
            + EXPENS_DAY + " integer,"
            + EXPENS_MONTH + " integer,"
            + EXPENS_YEAR + " integer,"
            + EXPENS_TYPE + " text,"
            + EXPENS_AMOUNT + " real,"
            + EXPENS_COMMENT + " text,"
            + EXPENS_PHOTO + " text,"
            + EXPENS_CUST + " text)";
    // + " FOREIGN KEY (" + CUST_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_CUST + "(" + CUST_ID + "));";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_EXPENSE_TABLE);

}


public  Cursor getSepficItem(){
    // Select All Query
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String q = "SELECT * FROM Expense";
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(q, null);
    // closing connection
    mCursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning customer
    return mCursor;
}
```

Logcat :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM Expense
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:58)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:132)
      at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:219)
      at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:258)
      at lu.digitalsecurity.expensenote.ReportActivity.createPdf(ReportActivity.java:89)
      at lu.digitalsecurity.expensenote.ReportActivity.onClick_report(ReportActivity.java:35)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Edit as requested :

XML file (only a simple button for the moment) :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".ReportActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_report">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:onClick="onClick_report"/>
```

Comment: post your activity XML and activity code

Comment: comment `mCursor.close();` getSepficItem()

Comment: You must not close a cursor nor the database until finished with the cursor else (well you now know). remove the 2 lines `mCursor.close();
    db.close();` from the `getSepficItem` method.

Comment: Do `mCursor.close()` and `db.close()` with Step 5 `document.close();` *note personally I tend to rarely close database often only in Main Activities `onDestroy` method*

Comment: @MikeT Thanks but I still have the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well actually the stack does tell you where the error is: "**attempt to re-open an already-closed object**".

When you do mCursor.close() basically you say the system "I won't use it anymore, you can free related resources".

IMHO you should have a class Expense, looking like:

```
public class Expense {
    private int id, day, month, year;
    private String type;
    // and so on...
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    // Other getters/setters

}
```

And your method getSepficItem() should returns a List:

```
public List<Expense> getSepficItem() {
    List<Expense> result = new ArrayList();
    // Select All Query
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String q = "SELECT * FROM Expense";
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(q, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Expense expense = new Expense();
            expense.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            // etc...
            expense.setType(cursor.getString(2));
            // etc...
            result.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    mCursor.close();
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

The the method that generates the PDF should use Expense, and not cursor.

Please note that it's not a full solution of your specific problem, rather  a clue on how to organise your code.

Finally adapt the pdf creation:

```
createPdf() {

  for (Expense expense : db.getSepficItem()) {
    // ..
    table.addCell(expense.getId());
  }
}
```

Comment: Well that's easier than dealing with Cursor... See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but now I have completely no idea on how I can use this to solve my problem. 

May I ask you to help me with more detail about this ?

Comment: Well I have just updated my answer. Again it's not a the full solution, only clue in the right direction.